# Automated translation management using Weblate (GitHub project)

Tags: c++, translation, build-automation, weblate

I'm new to git and forking and so. I want to contribute to a project that needs translation. The project uses Travis and AppVeyor.

Travis does the Mac and Linux builds, and AppVeyor does Windows. I already hooked them up to my fork on github to test out changes in the build scripts but I can't seem to find a way to link to Weblate.

I need help to figure out how I can set Weblate.

I was told to use Cmake to generate translation files. I'm a bit confused.

Please anybody helps here.

Update:
The project uses Qt so I just need it to generate .ts files which will be converted to .qm files. All I need to do is to setup Weblate so that people can translate the app and Travis and AppVeyor will be responsible for updating any changes.

So does anyone know how to setup [Weblate](http://weblate.org/)?